Visual representations of the Tripitaka
Are there visual representations of the Tripitaka? Its threefold division suggests a correspondence of vinaya to "body", sutta to "soul", abhidhamma to "mind", a rather broad correspondence that could be linked to many "threefold divisions" of symbolic language.  So I am asking for artistic works that focus explicitly on the Tripitaka, especially in Tibetan art.
